# Symmetric Group Acting on Direct Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I ran across this problem in my homework:

The symmetric group $Sn$ naturally acts on the set $J =$ {$1, 2, . . . , n$} of numbers from $1$ to $n$.

(a) Check that $σ(i,j)$ = $(σ(i),σ(j))$ defines an action of $Sn$ on the set $J × J$ of all pairs of elements from $J$.

(b) Show that $Sn$ has exactly two orbits in $J × J$.

(c) For each of these orbits, pick a representative (an element in the orbit) and find the stabilizer subgroup for this element.

I have worked out part A, but am at a total loss at how to do parts b and c. For part b, I assume you need to use that $|Ox|$=$[G/Gx]$; however, that theorem is not helpful in this case. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Any guesses what the two orbits are in part (b)? Did you try n=3 for example?

Comment: Deleted the previous comment. The two sets are: {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)} and {(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (3,2), (2,3)}, or one set with matching pairs, and the other containing the rest of the pairs from J x J

Comment: Yes. So, any guesses about the general n?

Comment: So, for the case of the general n, you will have 1 set of matching pairs from the set JxJ and another set consisting of the non matching pairs from JxJ. I'm not sure how you would write this formally though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the orbit $O_1$ which is the diagonal $\{ (n,n) \in J \times J\}$, and the rest $O_2 = J\times J \setminus O_1$. It is clear that $O_1$ forms an orbit. If you have $(m,n) \in O_2$, you may send it to any $(m',n) \in O_2$ through the transposition which swaps $m$, $m'$. Similarly for the second variable.

I'll let you figure out the stabilizers from there. As you have noted, the first stabilizer must have order $n!/n = (n-1)!$, and the second must have order $n!/(n(n-1)) = (n-2)!$. Hint: this suggests that they are themselves smaller symmetric groups embedded in $S_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand as my understanding of orbits is not the best. Why would this mean that G only has two orbits given your explanation––is this a property of orbits?

Comment: @RichardCao The orbits always partition a set. If we show that $O_1$ and $J\times J \setminus O_1$ are both orbits, then we are done, because we have exhausted all of $J \times J$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! Also, I can see that $O1$ is clearly an orbit. in regards to $O2$, why must it too be an orbit? Edit: I read your explanation more, is your reasoning since you can have (m, n) is an element of $O2$, and since Sn is a group of permutations, you can permute the initial m with any other m' in J, and a similar argument for n?

Comment: Because, as I explained, one can get from any element in $O_2$ to any other through group elements. This shows that $O_2$ belongs to a single orbit $O$ (i.e. $O_2 \subseteq O$). But since any element not in $O_2$ cannot belong to $O$ (as an element not in $O_2$ must by necessity belong to the orbit $O_1$, and orbits are disjoint), $O_2$ is actually the whole orbit $O$.

Comment: For example, if $n = 3$ and we want to go from $(1,2)$ to $(2,3)$ in $O_2$, we may first apply the transposition $(23)$ to $(1,2)$ to get $(1,3)$. Then, we may apply the transposition $(12)$ to get $(2,3)$. In other words, the group element $(12)(23) = (123) \in S_3$ get us from $(1,2)$ to $(2,3)$ in $O_2$. And one can argue similarly for any pair of elements in $O_2$, for any $n$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear. I also figured out part C! Take c and d to be elements of J, then the stabilizer group of (c, d) is just the subgroup of permutations that fix c and d correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Well done!